# Pathfinding on the surface with Marching cubes

Tags: path-finding, voxels, marching-cubes

I'm making a game where the world is made of 3D density field of Voxels.
And I use Marching Cubes to create a mesh using the Voxels.

It needs to be fast because You can modify terrain a lot.

Comment: It seems to me you could pathfind over the underlying voxel grid. Your navigable nodes are the empty voxels with a solid voxel below them to act as a floor. (And, potentially, an empty voxel or two above for headroom) Then you can search over these connected nodes with all the usual A* tricks and common optimizations. Where have you run into trouble applying conventional pathfinding approaches here?

Comment: Well the problem is that I need to know the slope, because there will be a max slope

Comment: Which you can compute from the adjacent voxels, right? Where does this present a problem?

Comment: How exactly would I do that.

Comment: Would you like to edit your question to ask "How to determine the surface slope from a grid of voxels"? It's a pretty straightforward application of [finite differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference), but if you need help with it I'm sure a user could provide an answer explaining in more detail.

Comment: Thanks I will look into that.